# When User sing in with their Google+ account, I can get all data, but only can't email. email=null and verified_email=false

Tags: c#, email, google-plus

```
     string URL=string.Format("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token={0}", googleresponse.access_token);

  private A GetGoogleUser<A>(string urluser) where A:class
        {
           A user = null;
            if (googleresponse != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(googleresponse.access_token))
            {                
                HttpWebRequest webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urluser);
                HttpWebResponse webresponse = (HttpWebResponse)webrequest.GetResponse();
                if (((HttpWebResponse)webresponse).StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    using (Stream recieveuser = webresponse.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
                        using (StreamReader readstream = new StreamReader(recieveuser, encode))
                        {
                            user = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<A>(readstream.ReadToEnd());
                            webresponse.Close();
                            readstream.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }                 
            }
            return  user;
        }
```

It is code that I can get User data When User `sign in` with their `Google+` account to my website.
Everthing is fine.
I can get User data`(id,name,gender,picture,link,family_name,locale)` , but only I can't email.

```
email=null
verified_email=false
```

But yesterday it was not so. I could get `email` too.

Does anyone know that where is my mistake ?

@@@.
.
.
I used only 
`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read` as `scope`, and 
`string URL=string.Format("https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?access_token={0}‌​‌​", googleresponse.access_token);` for creating `HttpWebRequest`. 
I can get all user's data, also `email`.

I wrote this here because may be other users can be use.

Comment: and `scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read scope. See https://developers.google.com/+/web/people/#retrieve_an_authenticated_users_email_address and https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth#email-scopes for more details.

**Update**

To be clear, you still need the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login scope in addition to the plus.profile.emails scope I mentioned above.

You'll still use the `plus.people.get` endpoint described at https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get

You should no longer use the `userinfo` endpoint - those have been deprecated and will be removed in September.

Comment: In C# code side , which endpoint should I use ? (for creating httpwebrequest)

Comment: I used `https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?access_token={0}` endpoit
and
 `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read`  scopes.

And I can get all data that I need.

Is this wrong ?
I hope this endpoint will not be removed.